# Javascript: Change <select ..> options from java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which looks like below, where the user can select multiple options. I am trying to do the same thing (when the page regenerates) from javascript. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could someone correct me?

```
            <form name="myForm">
                <select name="numSel[]" size="2" multiple="multiple">
                  <option value="ONE">ONE</option>                     
                  <option value="TWO">TWO</option>
                  <option value="THREE">THREE</option>
                  <option value="FOUR">FOUR</option>
                </select>
            </form>
```

This is the javascript code that I am trying (trying to select ONE and THREE):

```
                document.myForm.numSel.options[1].selected =  true;
                document.myForm.numSel.options[3].selected =  true;
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Syntax corrected (not actually in the code). I intend to generate the javascript statements in PHP and the numSel[] is needed for it to work. So, in this scenario, how do I change the code?

Thanks.

Comment: You have a syntax error `</selectt>` ??

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Select one and others get selected too? Be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JS code this way:

```
document.forms["myForm"].elements["numSel[]"].options[1].selected =  true;
document.forms["myForm"].elements["numSel[]"].options[3].selected =  true;
```

And correct the closing tag `</select>`.

Answer (score 2):

`name="numSel[]"` does not match the name in your script. Change that to just `numSel` and it works:

```
<select name="numSel" size="2" multiple="multiple">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5GJW/

.. or alternatively target it by the name "numSel[]"

```
document.myForm["numSel[]"].options[1].selected =  true;
document.myForm["numSel[]"].options[3].selected =  true;​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x3rGb/

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd solution worked and thanks for jsfiddle. Didn't know about it.

Comment: It's a great tool for testing javascript. Another similar/slightly more minimalist one, also useful, is http://jsbin.com. Mostly personal preference. (Strangely, though, jsbin is down right now)